# Xlsxwritter with Dataframe dont align text to left in the generated file(pandas / python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I'm creating an xlsx using pandas Dataframe and Xlsxwritter everything is generated correctly and the color styles are applied to the generated file, but the content text it's not aligned left as I apply to the dataframe with

```
df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

and also added the align left to the format that I applied to the workbook, but nothing solve the problem. there is my code [notebook](https://embed.deepnote.com/0963cdf6-9f1e-4d5c-841f-e98d445bdd71/513d3bf66edf44e4b77e199b8553cdd3/07fd04b5053246cfa89b7517d643a51d?height=2060).

Another question: How to unapply the sorting that groupby function apply to the dataframe ?